# Spring: "SimpleLogger does not seem to be location aware" exception

Tags: spring, log4j, slf4j

I'm getting an exception in a Spring app on my first line of code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

I have commons-logging-1.1.1.jar configured as a project library.

Here is the stack trace:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The logger [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)] does not seem to be location aware.

at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:347)
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:456)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:394)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using multiple logging frameworks at the same time.  This error seems to be a symptom of a clash between your SLF4J and Log4J configurations.

Take a look at this post:
http://www.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-user/2010-February/000892.html

which states,

> The code log(String FQCN, Priority p,
>   Object msg, Throwable t) method throws
>   an exception because the caller
>   expects location aware logging but the
>   actual logger implementation is not
>   capable of delivering "location
>   awareness".

Without more information, my best guess is that you have a reference to an slf4j jar like slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar or something else that's turning off logging by pointing to Non-Operational implementation of the Logger class.

Find the culprit and delete it (or replace it with the slf4j-log4j version).

Are you using Maven?

If so, open the dependency graph of your pom file and search for all dependencies with *slf4j* in their name.  Delete the one that looks like a NOOP jar.

Comment: This is a Spring/Hibernate project and somehow I had included both a versioned and an unversioned slf4j-simple.jar in the project as part of the Hibernate config. I deleted slf4j-simple.jar, leaving slf4j-simple-1.4.2.jar matching the slf4j-simple-api-1.4.2.jar that is part of the Hibernate distribution I'm using. All is well.

Comment: glad you sorted it out. I think, I like the theory behind SLF4J but in practice, it seems to cause a lot of problems like this.

Comment: What's really a pain is when the frameworks you're using have dependencies on logging systems and then you get snarled up in those. BLECH.