# Where do I get a proper Cassandra Thrift API jar file?

Tags: java, jar, cassandra, thrift, hector

Refer to [Is there a Java interface to Cassandra database that works out of the box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931771/is-there-a-java-interface-to-cassandra-database-that-works-out-of-the-box) for my original issue.

I determined that the cassandra thrift API jar file I downloade was incomplete or out of sync with the Hector API. Where can I download it? I haven't been able to find a download for it from the official site.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven repository are always a good choice for precompiled libs:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-thrift

It also lists all dependencies. You could also use a Maven file (or another compatible build system) to download the lib with all it's dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't an official jar that you can download. But you can grab the source-code here and compile it yourself:

http://thrift.apache.org/download/

If you use maven then you can just include the following in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download one of the release tgz files from https://github.com/rantav/hector/downloads it has the correct cassandra thrift to match the version of hector.